# AppCenter: build if commit message contains a specific string

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

Is it possible to configure Microsoft AppCenter to set build frequency on "Build this branch on every push" but to build if commit message contains a specific string for each push.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add [pre-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/#pre-build) script, do your check then call `exit 1` if needed,

reference: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/1574250f1947cf2f595d1b63414199b167087bf0/sample-build-scripts/xamarin/app-displayname/appcenter-pre-build.sh#L64

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic for this :

```
if ("git show $gitCommit || grep "regex" == false) 
 // { your code } do not deploy
else
// deploy
```